# Change drop down list depending on selection C#

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net, drop-down-menu, onselect

I have 2 drop down list `ddlcountry` and `DdPetPist`.
`ddlcountry` has its own table in MYSQL database and so dose `DdPetPist`, I would like `ddlcounty` selection to change the table populating `DdPetPist`. so change the table from `UK_Animals` to `France_Animals`. or `Germany_Animals.

**Code that populates drop down list**

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (!Page.IsPostBack)
            {
                MySqlCommand cd2 = new MySqlCommand("SELECT * FROM Country", cs); // need to make it so changes database
                cs.Open();
                MySqlDataReader ddlCountry = cd2.ExecuteReader();
                ddlcountry.DataSource = ddlCountry;
                ddlcountry.DataValueField = "Country";
                ddlcountry.DataTextField = "Country";
                ddlcountry.DataBind();
                cs.Close();
                cs.Dispose();

                MySqlCommand cd = new MySqlCommand("SELECT * FROM UK_Animals", cs);
                cs.Open();
                MySqlDataReader ddlSpecie = cd.ExecuteReader();
                DdPetPist.DataSource = ddlSpecie;
                DdPetPist.DataValueField = "Specie";
                DdPetPist.DataTextField = "Specie";
                DdPetPist.DataBind();
                cs.Close();
                cs.Dispose();
            }
```

**on select change for ddlcountry**

```
 protected void ddlcountry_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
```

Would relay appreciate it if anyone could help.

Comment: Your MySqlDatareader and dropdown has same name - ddlcountry. Change one of them first.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hope that I have understand correctly:

```
protected void ddlcountry_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  if(ddlcountry.Text!=string.Empty)
  {
      MySqlCommand cd = new MySqlCommand(string.Format("SELECT * FROM {0}_Animals",ddlcountry.Text), cs);
      cs.Open();
      MySqlDataReader ddlSpecie = cd.ExecuteReader();
      DdPetPist.DataSource = ddlSpecie;
      DdPetPist.DataValueField = "Specie";
      DdPetPist.DataTextField = "Specie";
      DdPetPist.DataBind();
      cs.Close();
      cs.Dispose();
  }
}
```

Comment: I'm not 100% sure how ASP.Net does validation of dropdown values, but make sure that a hacker can't change the country value in the HTML to something like `Users --` (which could select from your user account table, if you had one). Best approach would likely be to chop off all but the first two characters from the country name.

Answer (score 2):

Try this

I am assuming that ddlcountry contain exactly same name of country as the table name.(ie UK ,France etc) and table names (UK_Animals, France_Animals)

```
protected void ddlcountry_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string country = ddlcountry.SelectedValue;
    string query =  "SELECT * FROM "+ country + "_Animals";   

     MySqlCommand cd = new MySqlCommand(query, cs);
     cs.Open();
     MySqlDataReader ddlSpecie = cd.ExecuteReader();
     DdPetPist.DataSource = ddlSpecie;
     DdPetPist.DataValueField = "Specie";
     DdPetPist.DataTextField = "Specie";
     DdPetPist.DataBind();
     cs.Close();
     cs.Dispose();
}
```

Comment: Thank you it dose work, unfortunately I have already accepted @Tinwor answer that works to. thank you anyway.